# Ethereum Wallet app Synced, coinbase transaction not appearing

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, coinbase

My ETH wallet app has synced and the new blocks it loads every time I re-open the Wallet starts to sync. The issue is that I sent ETH from Coinbase to My ETH wallet and it is not showing now. Etherscan shows it was validated with my correct address almost 19 hours ago (the sync should have already covered those blocks by now).

Also, every time I open the Wallet App again, and it loads the blocks, once it finishes it seems to reboot and somehow close out all my programs and then send me to my account login screen for Mac. As if I just shut down the computer. Not sure how this affects it but seems to be connected. I am using a 2016 Mac and the most up to date version of ETH Wallet app from Ethereum.org.

I have tried to delete all the chain data and resync which didn't change anything. Again the address matches the Etherscan and it shows it to be validated but the wallet app seems to have the issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try MetaMask (the chrome plugin) and import the key file for your ether wallet app from your %Appdata%/Ethereum folder.